# Changing Scriplet to Servlet simple case

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl, scriptlet

I have a question I have really simple scriplet code to retrive data from database and then plot it on the graph. Should I consider to change that code to servlet?
Here is the code:

```
 <% 
                                 int sum=0;
                                 int all=0;
                                 int userID=-1;
                                 int EcimNum=0;
                                 int CommNum=0;
                                 int AppNum=0;
                                 int InstNum=0;
                                 String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/imf_jsp";
                                 Connection connection = null;
                                 PreparedStatement st;
                                 ResultSet rs = null;
                                 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); 
                                 connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "");
                                 if(!connection.isClosed())
                                 {
                                 st = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM user WHERE signum = ?"); //Find user with given username & pass
                                 st.setString(1, session.getAttribute("username").toString());//Bind param (Should prevent SQL Injection? Not sure but it is working in PHP with PDO)
                                 st.execute();//statemant execution

                                 rs = st.getResultSet();
                                 if(rs.next()){
                                     userID = rs.getInt("id");//If not then check in LDAP

                                     }
                                 }
                                 st = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM model INNER JOIN user ON model.user_id=user.id WHERE model_type='ECIM' AND user.id = ?"  );
                                 st.setInt(1, userID);
                                 st.execute();
                                 rs = st.getResultSet();
                                 if(rs.next()){
                                     EcimNum = rs.getInt("COUNT(*)");//If not then check in LDAP   
                                     System.out.println(EcimNum);
                                     sum+=EcimNum;
                                     }

                                 st = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM model INNER JOIN user ON model.user_id=user.id WHERE model_type='Common' AND user.id = ?");
                                 st.setInt(1, userID);
                                 st.execute();
                                 rs = st.getResultSet();
                                 if(rs.next()){
                                     CommNum = rs.getInt("COUNT(*)");//If not then check in LDAP   
                                     System.out.println(CommNum);
                                     sum+=CommNum;
                                     }
                                 st = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM model INNER JOIN user ON model.user_id=user.id WHERE model_type='Application' AND user.id = ?");
                                 st.setInt(1, userID);
                                 st.execute();
                                 rs = st.getResultSet();
                                 if(rs.next()){
                                     AppNum = rs.getInt("COUNT(*)");//If not then check in LDAP   
                                     System.out.println(AppNum);
                                     sum+=AppNum;
                                     }
                                 st = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM model INNER JOIN user ON model.user_id=user.id WHERE model_type='Instance' AND user.id = ?");
                                 st.setInt(1, userID);
                                 st.execute();
                                 rs = st.getResultSet();
                                 if(rs.next()){
                                     InstNum = rs.getInt("COUNT(*)");//If not then check in LDAP   
                                     System.out.println(InstNum);
                                     sum+=InstNum;
                                     }
                                 st = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM model ");
                                 st.execute();
                                 rs = st.getResultSet();
                                 if(rs.next()){
                                     all = rs.getInt("COUNT(*)");//If not then check in LDAP   
                                     System.out.println(all);

                                     }

%>  
                    <p>User Name: ${username} <br>Number Of Models Upladed: <% out.print(sum); %></br>Procentage of total:<%out.print((sum*100)/all); %>%</p>
```

What is better solution for that problem? The only thing that single page is doing is just getting data for a single user. But in the future I am planing doing admin version where admin will be able to see all users statistics. Tell me what do you think about it

Comment: Move it to a Servlet. Scriptlets are bad. Scriptlets that access the database are really bad. It's mixing code and markup.

Comment: You can see that in that scriplet I have variables that are counting items in the DB. I pass them to the js function. Will I be able to do something like that when I use servlet. I know that you can set response attributes etc. so then would I be able to do something like that `var allModels=${allModelsCount}` ??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have taken a right decision to move your logic to a servlet. Scriptlets are bad and business logic shouldn't be tightly coupled to the presentation layer. In Both cases (viewing Single user data / Many user data), you can perform the business logic and once you have the data in your servlet code, you can set them to a collection of your POJO objects like `ArrayList<User>` instance in which you can set the `User` objects. Once you have the collection ready, you can set it by `request.setAttribute(#LIST_OBJ);` and send it back in the response. To iterate the list, you can use JSTL for showing them in JSP

Comment: I done it that way because I change php code to JSP. Scriplets look similar to the php code or is it just my impression?
I was just wondering if I use servlet and get request that will mean that if somone change ID in url to another user ID he will be able to see his stats and I do not want to do that.

Comment: yes, PHP and JSP are both similar technologies. In Java world, JSP is meant to be for presentation, though it has capabilities of performing logical operations using Scriptlets. so, Don't use scriptlets. To secure you web-app, there are lot of options, you have. Learn how to secure webapp in Java. Simply, you can have your own logic to secure your page in your servlet code itself.

Comment: App is secure in terms of XSS and SQL injection additionally it is in intranet so it should be really well protected.